# Image stiching with sift/SURF

Tags: c#, image-processing

I have a general question. Infact I need an idea of Image stiching using SIFT/ SURF.
Normally pairwise technique is used in SIFT/SURF. But what will be procedure if I want to use SIFT/SURF for n images. Should I proceed {(1...n),(2,...n),(3,..n)...} or there is an other fast procedure. Any idea and code (if available) will be appreciated.
regards,

Comment: You might need to expand your description of the pairwise technique and your proposed improvement ..

Answer (score 0):

If you merge 1 with 2, then you only need to merge 3 with the resulting image, no?

It's possible that you might improve performance by taking pairs and processing them concurrently, then pairs of pairs, and so on until you had no pairs left to merge.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your suggestion, or this would only work if every pair of images overlapped? If every image only overlapped with a few others, then you'd have to match all N images to find the ones that overlap, right?

Comment: Eventually you would match all images -- I'd assume that if a match wasn't possible then no resulting image would be produced, and the pair would go back in the pool. At worst, it'd be as bad as comparing every image with every other image.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea: If you have the SIFT features from all images, you could compare every feature with every other feature and start with the features with the highest similarity that haven't been matched yet. It's likely that that feature pair belongs to two images that overlap. Try to match those pairwise - if the fit, repeat, otherwise try again with the next best feature match.